# svg image not displaying in mobile emulators

Tags: angular, svg, android-emulator, ionic3, ripple

I am testing ioinc cordova app in ripple emulator the below svg data points are not displaying correctly in the ripple emulator, where as the image is displaying perfectly in the browser, here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNm8W/6498/)

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><defs><pattern id="sign-0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Pisces.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Aquarius.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Capricorn.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Saggitarius.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Aries.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-7" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Scorpio.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Taurus.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-11" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Libra.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-12" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Gemeni.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-13" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Cancer.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-14" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/leo.png"></image></pattern><pattern id="sign-15" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="25" width="25"><image x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12.5" xlink:href="http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Virgo.png"></image></pattern></defs><g transform="translate(0,0)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-0)" id="b0"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t0">9.21 Su</text><text font-size="3" x="5" y="6" id="t0">27.42 Me</text><text font-size="3" x="5" y="9" id="t0">19.14 Ju</text><text font-size="3" x="5" y="12" id="t0">6.41 Ur</text></g><g transform="translate(0,25)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-1)" id="b1"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t1">2.29 Ve</text><text font-size="3" x="5" y="6" id="t1">29. Ma</text><text font-size="3" x="5" y="9" id="t1">5.37 Ne</text></g><g transform="translate(0,50)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-2)" id="b2"></rect></g><g transform="translate(0,75)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-3)" id="b3"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t3">13.25 Pl</text><text font-size="3" x="5" y="6" id="t3">3.22 Ra</text></g><g transform="translate(25,0)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-4)" id="b4"></rect></g><g transform="translate(25,25)"><rect width="50" height="50" border="1" stroke="black" fill="#f4a460" id="b5"></rect><text fill="white" font-size="5" x="10" y="25" id="t5">BIRTH CHART</text></g><g transform="translate(25,75)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-7)" id="b7"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t7">13.11 Mo</text></g><g transform="translate(50,0)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-8)" id="b8"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t8">22 AC</text></g><g transform="translate(50,75)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-11)" id="b11"></rect></g><g transform="translate(75,0)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-12)" id="b12"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t12">3.22 Ke</text></g><g transform="translate(75,25)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-13)" id="b13"></rect></g><g transform="translate(75,50)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-14)" id="b14"></rect></g><g transform="translate(75,75)"><rect width="25" height="25" border="1" stroke="black" fill="url(#sign-15)" id="b15"></rect><text font-size="3" x="5" y="3" id="t15">20.40 Sa</text></g></svg>
```

If it does not display correctly in ripple emulator then I am guessing that the same impact on mobile devices as well. Any suggestion how to fix the issue?

[image: svg image displayed in ripple emulator]

**UPDATE-1:**
In Edge simulator boxes are displaying, images not displaying though and there is scaling issue as well maybe something to do with viewBox attribute???
[image]

Below is the code snippet which generates the grid system

```
grid(numberPerSide, size, pixelsPerSide, plps) {
        var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(svg, "width", pixelsPerSide);
        //this.renderer.setAttribute(svg, "height", height);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(svg, "viewBox", [0, 0, numberPerSide * size, numberPerSide * size].join(" "));
        var defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");
        var pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "id", "sign-0");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern,"patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        //this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "height", size);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "width", size);
        var image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "x", "0");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "y", "0");
        //this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "height", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Pisces.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);

        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "id", "sign-1");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        //this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "height", size);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(pattern, "width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "x", "0");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "y", "0");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "height", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Aquarius.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-2");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Capricorn.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-3");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Saggitarius.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-4");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Aries.png");

        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);

        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-7");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Scorpio.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-8");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Taurus.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-11");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Libra.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-12");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Gemeni.png");
        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-13");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Cancer.png");

        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-14");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/leo.png");

        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
        pattern.setAttribute("id", "sign-15");
        pattern.setAttribute("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        pattern.setAttribute("height", size);
        pattern.setAttribute("width", size);
        image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        image.setAttribute("x", "0");
        image.setAttribute("y", "0");
        image.setAttribute("height", size / 2);
        image.setAttribute("width", size / 2);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(image, "xlink:href",
                             "http://live.makemypublication.com/Images/Virgo.png");

        this.renderer.appendChild(pattern, image);
        this.renderer.appendChild(defs, pattern);
        this.renderer.appendChild(svg, defs);
        var border = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < numberPerSide; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < numberPerSide; j++) {
                if ((i * numberPerSide + j) == 5 || (i * numberPerSide + j) == 6 || (i * numberPerSide + j) == 9 || (i * numberPerSide + j) == 10) {
                    if ((i * numberPerSide + j) == 5) {
                        var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(g, "transform", ["translate(", i * size, ",", j * size, ")"].join(""));
                        var number = numberPerSide * i + j;
                        var box = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "width", size * 2);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "height", size * 2);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "border", border);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "stroke", "black");
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "fill", "#f4a460");
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "id", "b" + number);
                        this.renderer.appendChild(g, box);
                        var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
                        this.renderer.appendChild(text, document.createTextNode("BIRTH CHART"));
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "fill", "white");
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "font-size", 5);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "x", size * 2 / 5);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "y", size * 2 / 2);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "id", "t" + number);
                        g.appendChild(text);
                        svg.appendChild(g);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                // var zodiac1 = zodiacs[(i + j) % zodiacs.length];
                // var zodiac2 = zodiacs[(i + j + 1) % zodiacs.length];
                g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
                this.renderer.setAttribute(g, "transform", ["translate(", i * size, ",", j * size, ")"].join(""));
                number = numberPerSide * i + j;
                box = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
                var sign = "url(#sign-" + number.toString() + ")";
                this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "width", size);
                this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "height", size);
                this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "border", border);
                this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "stroke", "black");
                this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "fill", sign);
                this.renderer.setAttribute(box, "id", "b" + number);
                this.renderer.appendChild(g, box);
                sign = signs[number];
                if (plps.hasOwnProperty(sign)) {
                    //var pls = replaceAll(plps[sign], '\|', '');
                    //var pls = plps[sign].replace(/\|/g, ' ');
                    var pls = plps[sign].split('\|');
                    var pcnt = 0;
                    for (var k = 0; k < pls.length; k++) {
                        if (pls[k].split(' ')[1] == 'me' || pls[k].split(' ')[1] == 'os') continue;
                        if (pls[k].split(' ')[1] == 'AC') this.asc_sign = sign;
                        else if (pls[k].split(' ')[1] == 'Mo') {
                            this.moon_sign = sign;
                            this.moon_deg = Number(pls[k].split(' ')[0]);
                        }
                        pcnt++;
                        text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
                        this.renderer.appendChild(text, document.createTextNode(pls[k]));
                        //text.setAttribute("fill", zodiac2);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "font-size", 3);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "x", 5);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "y",  3 * pcnt);
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(text, "id", "t" + number);
                        g.appendChild(text);
                    }
                }
                svg.appendChild(g);
            }
        }
        g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(g, "transform", ["translate(", i * size, ",", j * size, ")"].join(""));
        number = numberPerSide * i + j;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (o_signs[i] == this.asc_sign) {
                //if (plPos.hasOwnProperty(this.asc_sign)) {
                    this.trikona_lords = rashi_lords[o_signs[i]];
                    this.kendra_lords = rashi_lords[o_signs[i]];
                //}
                var as = 1;
                rashis[this.asc_sign] = '1|' + rashis[this.asc_sign].split('\|')[1];
                for (j = i + 1; j < 12; j++) {
                    as++;
                    rashis[o_signs[j]] = (as).toString() + '|' + rashis[o_signs[j]].split('\|')[1];
                    //if (plPos.hasOwnProperty(o_signs[j])) {
                        if (as == 5 || as == 9) {
                            this.trikona_lords = this.trikona_lords + '|' + rashi_lords[o_signs[j]];
                        }
                        else if (as == 4 || as == 7 || as == 10) {
                            this.kendra_lords = this.kendra_lords + '|' + rashi_lords[o_signs[j]];
                        }
                    //}
                }
                for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    var hno = ((12 - i) + (k + 1));
                    rashis[o_signs[k]] = hno.toString() + '|' + rashis[o_signs[k]].split('\|')[1];
                    //if (plPos.hasOwnProperty(o_signs[k])) {
                        if (hno == 5 || hno == 9) {
                            this.trikona_lords = this.trikona_lords + '|' + rashi_lords[o_signs[k]];
                        }
                        else if (hno == 4 || hno == 7 || hno == 10) {
                            this.kendra_lords = this.kendra_lords + '|' + rashi_lords[o_signs[k]];
                        }
                    //}
                }
            }
        }

        return svg;
    };
```

Thanks for your time & attention

Comment: when i open chrome dev tools then all boxes are displayed but not images at least the svg image is rendering ok, does this require reload after drawing

Comment: in Edge simulator boxes are ok images not displaying though and there is a scaling issue as well